# Conversion between DTO and Entity using Interface

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, type-conversion, dto

Is it ok to use an Interace for converting between DTO and Entity?

```
public interface UserDto {
    public long getId();
    public String getName();
    public String getEmail();
    public String getPassword();
}

public interface UserEntity extends UserDto {
    public long getUuId();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For most cases, I would say no because the properties are different between them and should be independent of each other hence a custom implementation with an interface is not the ultimate solution.

I'd recommend using `mapstruct` library instead, which also works with interfaces under the hood. You define the interface, and it will generate the boilerplate code for you, resulting in much more maintainable code:

```
@Mapper 
public interface UserMapper{
    @Mappings(
             @Mapping(target = "id", source = "id"),
             @Mapping(target = "name", source = "name"),
             @Mapping(target = "email", source = "email"),
             @Mapping(target = "password", source = "password")
            })

    UserEntity mapDtoToEntity(UserDto usertDto);
}
```

If your mappings are simple enough, go with `ModelMapper` or Spring's `BeanUtils.copyProperties`. If you really want to map them yourself, I'd suggest avoiding mixing them up with an interface and keeping them independent from each other.

Answer (score 1):

**Use de convert interface**

ModelMapper is deprecated already, the interface converter is the best way.

```
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;

public class UserEntityToUserDTO implements Converter<UserEntity, UserDTo>
    {
    
        @Override
        public UserDTo convert(UserEntity source) 
        {
            //map the fields to dto object
        }
        
    }
```